# Adding days to input date with strange console log results

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I'm trying to return a date in format i.e(12-5-2013) to the variable 'returningOn' by adding 'stayingFor' days number to the formatted 'dateObj' in the same format.

But i seem to be getting bizarre values when i do some console.logs. Why is this? Also, What date format is the last variable in?

```
var leavingOn = $('#leavingOn') != 'undefined' ? $('#leavingOn').val() : '12-7-2013';
var stayingFor = $('#stayingFor') != 'undefined' ? $('#stayingFor').val() : 7 ;
var splitDate = leavingOn.split('-');
var dateObj = new Date(Number(splitDate[0]), Number(splitDate[1]) -1, Number(splitDate[2]));
var returningOn = dateObj.setDate(dateObj.getDate() + stayingFor);

console.log(splitDate);  //  ["2013", "11", "14"]
console.log(leavingOn);  //   2013-11-14
console.log(stayingFor);  //  7
console.log(dateObj);  // Fri Jul 25 2014 22:00:07 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
console.log(returningOn);  // 1406322007249
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the stayingFor variable needs to be converted to an integer. Try:

stayingFor = parseInt(stayingFor);

Comment: Thanks for the repsonse. Now i've changed the above line the 4th console.log now reads 'Sun Jun 26 1932 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)'. Any ideas why? i may miss the obvious 12hours into coding in a day.

Comment: I changed the top lines tertinary value to this YYYY-MM-DD format just to mention, although this isnt selected as default, todays date is earlier on in my script using 'new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10)'

Comment: I think the stayingFor variable needs to be converted to an integer. Try: stayingFor = parseInt(stayingFor). The weird date was arising because the string value, instead of an integer, was being added and therefore giving unexpected results.

Comment: Just did this and then came to your answer, i added it in this line if it helps anyone else: var returningOn1 = dateObj.setDate(dateObj.getDate() + parseInt(stayingFor1));